# Decode Hex string to UTF-16?

Tags: powershell, unicode, hex, utf-16

I am trying to understand and extract data from a database. The critical information seems to be encoded as a HEX string in one of the tables. When I tried to convert that to ASCII, it gives me gibberish. There are other files used in conjunction with this database that I believe are encoded as Unicode UTF-16. So I'd like to try and convert this hex string to UTF-16 and see what it looks like.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this in Powershell?

Thanks

Comment: why are you believing it's UTF-16? Does it have a lot of zeros in the high bytes? Show some examples here

Comment: How about saving it to a file probably as a byte array, then opening the file as encoding unicode?  What does the string look like?

Comment: phuclv, I am basing it off of the fact that the text I think it reflects is utf-16. I think it is encoding a portion of a texx file that is utf-16.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string consists of an even number of hexadecimal characters you could insert a delimiter character after every 2 characters, remove a trailing delimiter (to not generate a trailing empty element), and then split the string at the delimiter.

```
$s = 'a3422b4a'
$s -replace '..', '$&:' -replace ':$' -split ':'
```

Then cast the resulting fragments to bytes:

```
... | ForEach-Object { [byte]"0x$_" }
```

Collect the byte array in a variable and convert it to a Unicode string:

```
[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes)
```

`[Text.Encoding]::Unicode` is UTF-16 LE. Use `[Text.Encoding]::BigEndianUnicode` if you need UTF-16 BE.

---

**Edit:** On second thought, you don't even need the loop for the conversion. You could insert the `0x` before each pair of hexadecimal characters and split the string at characters followed by the sequence `0x`, then cast the resulting array to a byte array.

```
[byte[]]($s -replace '..', '0x$&' -split '(?<=.)(?=0x)')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and let you know if it worked!

Comment: Well, I got something to work using the long way you first mentioned. But my output is all random asian characters.  So that's probably not right.  Your method is probably good, it's probably just not encoded exactly as I thought.

What I actually have is "0x" followed by a long hex string. In the case of the shortest one it is about 400 characters long, but each one varies. Any idea what that might be respresenting?

Comment: @ARZ2019 No. You need to provide more information for that. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57977979/edit) your question and provide a) sample data, b) the code you used to process the data, and c) the output that code produced.